# Add image into list through SVG

Tags: html, css, image, svg, html-lists

I am trying to get this working for the contact area: http://jsfiddle.net/y8zx3/

CSS:

```
#container #sidebar ul.kontakt { list-style: none }
#container #sidebar ul.kontakt li {
    /* display: block; */
    line-height: 70px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    float: right;
    display: list-item;
}
#container #sidebar ul.kontakt li svg {
    /* position: relative;;*/
    float: left;
}
#container #sidebar ul.kontakt li a {
    /* display: block; */
    line-height: 70px;
    margin: 0;
    float: right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<h1>Kontakt</h1>
<p>Schön, das Sie uns kontaktieren wollen. Sie können uns entweder per Kontaktformular erreichen, oder ganz traditionell per Telefon, Email oder Fax.</p>
<ul class="kontakt">
    <li>
        <svg height="50px" id="Layer_1" style="enable-background:new 0 4 512 512;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="512px" x="0px" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" y="0px">
            <g>
                <polygon points="448,384 448,141.8 316.9,241.6 385,319 383,321 304.1,251.4 256,288 207.9,251.4 129,321 127,319 195,241.6    64,142 64,384  " />
                <polygon points="439.7,128 72,128 256,267.9  " />
            </g>
        </svg><a href="mailto:info@immobilienverwaltung-buerk.de">info@immobilienverwaltung-buerk.de</a>
    </li>
    <li>+49 (0) 7127 980 1493
        <li>+49 (0) 7127 980 1489</li>
        <li>+49 (0) 160 16 25 175</li>
</ul>
```

I want the email icon to be at the left of the list, but dont want to do this using css background-image. How could I achieve this? right now the image is above the li and not in front. Btw the icon is an inline SVG. See http://jsfiddle.net/y8zx3/ for full co

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a little bit of CSS editing using Chrome's Developer Tools (Very Useful!)

```
/* On #container #sidebar ul.kontakt li */
width: 100%;
text-align: right;

/* On #container #sidebar ul.kontakt li svg */
margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
```

Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/bnkAL/

**Edit #1**

Set the width of the SVG from 512px to 50px ... The SVG is expanded past the `<li>`, pushing the `<a>` tag down.

```
...viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="50px" x="0px"...
```

Comment: Works in the jsfiddle, but not in chrome.